# Overlap images in view in android

Tags: android

I need to create a layout containing two images .(I am attaching the image file along).The images should be such that the first should overlap over the second.Can some body please help me as i am a newbie to android any help will be appreciable.There are actually two images one plain image and another having slanting lines.I want to make the resultant image appear something like the following [image]

Comment: A simple code on XML would be nice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need a frame layout something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"/>
```

This will layout items on top of each other. :)