# aligning 2 imageViews in a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with aligning 2 imageviews in a RelativeLayout:

[image: problem]

these 2 images need to be close to eatch other without space. Like this:
[image: target]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_portrait"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- header -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dia1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/dia1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dia2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dia1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/dia2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE
dia1 is:
[image: dia1]

dia2 is:
[image: dia2]

Comment: Can you upload your Images too?
If your Images are cropped in a straight line...
Then two possible issues can be..
1. If your drawables have extra transparent space left, as i can see in first image, need to remove that.
2. If, after cropping also the issue remains then better set Imageview background not src.

Comment: Could you update your question with the whole layout and a better indication about which `drawable` is which?

Answer (score 0):

From the 1st picture you posted, it seems the bottom image has a great deal of transparent "padding" (not actual padding, just transparent image pixels between the visible part and the upper limit).

In my opinion, you should combine `RelativeLayout` with cropped versions of your upper and lower images.

Otherwise, consider checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771261/overlap-images-in-view-in-android) SO thread about overlapping images.

Comment: absolutelayout is deprecated :)

Comment: @user1104939 I'm so freaking stupid. Thanks for the reminder. (edited my post)

Comment: oh and both images are perfectly cropped btw, but for some reason the view gets to big :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't explain much about the problem. So you can add a single image. I mean merge the 2 images before and use it as 1.

Comment: No they need to stay separated for future use :)

Comment: Before using the 2 images confirm they don't have a white border. secondly, instead of using match_parent as layout_width, try using wrap_content. This ensures that no extra padding is there.

Comment: both images are cropped, and wrap_content doesnt change a thing :S